# div tag's height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a tree(jstree) inside a div, so when a node gets expanded the div's height changes. I want to get the div's height on each expansion of node or just the final div height. jquery is advisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 $("#Your-div-id").height();
```

You can bind a click function on your jstree and on each click you can calculate your div height.

see [this](http://www.jstree.com/demo) and http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core

Comment: @LenSmith: In case the exact div height matters, please note that `height()` does not include padding, borders or margins of the element. If you need to include any of those, look at using the alternative methods `innerHeight()` or `outerHeight()` instead. For more details on those see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11248902/448144

Comment: Is there a way to find out the height of jstree expanded form?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply following event script, It should work when tree node has open event occurred.

```
$("#demo1").bind("open_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        $("#Your-div-id").height('auto');
});
```