# Jquery Simple Hide Div but setting a smaller height

Tags: jquery, css

Why does this code attempt to hide the div but then show it again? using firefox

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#tool1").click(function(){
       if($('#status').height() > 100){
           $('#status').css('height','50px').show();
       }    
    });

});
```

Thanks for the help so far they all worked. However this is the exact code I have
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GdhS4/2/)

Comment: `Why does this code attempt to hide the div `... Not sure where it tries to hide the div, it merely sets it to a height of 50px. I don't see any code trying to hide the div.

Comment: I simply want it to minimise the height down to 50px when #tool1 is clicked then if clicked again rezize back upto the original 250px height set in css. Sorry first day at jquery

Comment: As a general side-note: jQuery `height()` only returns the height of the element not including any paddings, borders or margins. If you need to include those in your code you can use the alternate methods of `innerHeight` and `outerHeight`. For more info, including a demo on all of those methods see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11248902/448144

Comment: This is more like the code I have something weird going on.http://jsfiddle.net/GdhS4/2/

Comment: The only thing I see in your fiddle is that tools1 is a link not a button, clicking the link casues a submit which causes a delay as the page refreshes.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl yes it now works if I remove the href

Comment: If you don't want to remove it, you can just have <a href="javascript: void(0);"> or <a href="#">. But that's where your problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#tool1").click(function(){
   if($('#status').height() > 100){
     $('#status').hide(500, function() {  // hide the div
        $(this)
             .css('height','50px')  // change the height
             .show(500); // then show again
     });
   }    
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/573/)**

#### According to above comment

```
$("#tool1").click(function(){
   var orig = $('#status').height(),
       target = orig == 250 ? 50 : 250;
       $('#status').animate({
           height: target      
       },1000);  
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/575/)**

#### According to below comment

- Button is inside `#status`

**[Button inside demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/579/)**

### According to your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GdhS4/2/)

Change you code like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tool1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // preventDefault() for pare reload
        var $statusDiv = $('#status');
        if ($statusDiv.height() > 100) {
            $statusDiv.height(50);
        }
        else {
            $statusDiv.height(250);
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GdhS4/4/)**

#### Note

***You can also remove `href`*** from `#tool1`

Currently `#tool1` is link tag, if you want to use a button, than just remove `e.preventDefault()` from above code.

Comment: @Harry check my second demo, I think you want that

Comment: The button #tool1 is inside the div #status would that cause any trouble here? Still not working

Comment: @Harry check button inside demo

Comment: @thecodeparadox: Clicking the button realy fast seems to crash something as it stops resizing the div after a few fast clicks. Not sure why.

Comment: @Harry I've also shared also your code in my last demo with slight change

Comment: @Harry: If you intend to use a link instead of a button but all you want is resize the div. Just leave tools1 a button or div and use styles to make it look like a link rather than trying to compensate for a page reload.

Comment: Your last demo worked e.preventDefault(); fixed it. Alternatively remove the href part out of the link. Got there in the end :)

Comment: In the end it all came down to a simplistic height adjustment, same as my answer :) +1 though @thecodeparadox for all the variants and work :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your feedback if all you want is switch the height of the status div between 250 and 50 you can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tool1").click(function() {
        var $statusDiv = $('#status');
        if ($statusDiv.height() > 100) {
            $statusDiv.height(50);
        }
        else
        {
            $statusDiv.height(250);
        }
    });
});
```

I based this on Html as you outlined in other comments:

```
<div id="status">
    <button id="tool1">
        tool 1 div
    </button>
</div>
```

I applied a default style of 250 height and a border for visual presentation:

```
#status{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 250px;
}
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GdhS4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `show()` jQuery animation by adding:

```
jQuery.fx.off = true;
```

code line.

Read [more](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fx.off/) about this property.