# How do you calculate parent div height every time (when user fresh browser multiple times)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent div that is in `position:relative` and I have a child div which is in `position:absolute`. I want to calculate the height of the parent div on load which I'm able to do with the jquery below. I'm also able to recalculate the height dynamically when user resize the browser, which is what I want.

The issue I'm having is sometime when user refresh the page a few times the jquery don't seem to be running as it is unable to calculate the height on first load. How do I always force it to wait for the child div to load and then get the height.

This is the jquery I've got

```js
$(function() {
  //Calculate the height on first load
  $('.OV2-img, .col1').height($('.col1-img').outerHeight());
  //Calculate the height on browser resize
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.OV2-img, .col1').height($('.col1-img').outerHeight());
  });
});
```

Hope I'm clear here. Honestly I'm very bad with JS.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers for now

**Solutions found**
Thanks to **Mosh Feu** for the great recommendation. So now I change the code to this:-

```
$(function () {
//Calculate the height on first load
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.OV2-img, .col1').height($('.col1-img').outerHeight());
});
  //Calculate the height on browser resize
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.OV2-img, .col1').height($('.col1-img').outerHeight());
});
});
```

Thanks everyone for your kind help.

Please refer to the below URL to see what I'm trying to do. Basically this allow me to retain the spacing between the image and the colour box on any screen size.

[View On Codepen](https://codepen.io/upgradeboliao/pen/WJMoyO)

Comment: A. You can debug it when it doesn't work and see what wrong. B. You can try to call it in `$(window).load` rather than `$(document).ready` maybe there are some changes in the DOM that sometimes happening after document ready.

Comment: Can you show your markup, I believe this is possible by only CSS.

Comment: do you try using **vh** in css? 
`.page-banner { height: 100vh; }`
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative-lengths

Comment: try to use wrap your function inside `setTimeout()` function...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on document ready,

```
var newHeight = $(".OV2-img, .col1").height();
$(".col1-img").height(newHeight);
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more details please visit, [Calculate the width and height of parent div and apply to image accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677222/calculate-the-width-and-height-of-parent-div-and-apply-to-image-accordingly)

Comment: Thanks but don't seem to work. Got it to work using window.load which I understand now.

Comment: ok, then update your working code in the answer. So, others will get the solution from here.

Answer (score 0):

As Hanif pointed out, there might be a solution in pure CSS. Without further knowing anything about your actual design, I've assumed you want an `div` inside another `div`, to be the same size. I've made some code here.

```css
.rel {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 4rem;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 3rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.4);
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Some Showcase</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="rel">
    Content Is King
    <div class="abs">
       Content, Maybe?
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice, that you don't have to use `height: 100%;`. You can use any size you want, like `80%` or `12em`. Maybe even `calc()` could be handy.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. Sorry I was not clear. I can't control the height of the child div (which has image) and the parent must always have the height of the child. Thus I can't just use CSS as I can't I assign a fixed height to both parent and child. Thus the need for me to use js to solve that and address the responsive part.

Comment: Is there only one child element per parent element with `position: absolute;`?

Comment: If there is really only one element, with `position: absolute;`, I would change it to `position: relative;`....

Comment: Nope, there are 2 child in the parent. Let me try to figure out how I can put up the code so all can see them.

Comment: I've created a codepen to show what I'm trying to do. https://codepen.io/upgradeboliao/pen/WJMoyO. Cheers for now

Comment: Yeah, it seems that approach with JavaScript is probably fast and simple; I'm clueless how to solve this challenge with CSS only (without questioning the design restrictions).